# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed Visual Basics

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am struggling to get my code to run and would really appreciate some help as it is my first time working with Visual Basics.

Error:
Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Part of code highlighted as error:

```
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("Ai"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Yellow arrow next to this line: MatchCase:=False).Row

Solution:
Changed

```
After:=Range("Ai"), _
```

to

```
After:=Range("A" & Rows.Count), _
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
After:=Range("Ai"), _
```

with

```
After:=Range("A" & i), _
```

Anyhow, a simple way of obtaining the last row of A:A column would be:

```
LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row
```

Comment: I just tried changing it, but I still get the same error

Comment: When I say debug...it makes an yellow arrow next to my last line of code,,,not sure if that is maybe the problem?

Comment: But did you give to `i` variable a value? I thought that your piece of code is part of an iteration using `i`... Try `i = 2`. Why do you need `i`, if you do not use it?

Comment: This is the whole code:Sub addData()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, nextBlankRow As Long
lastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A" & i), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

nextBlankRow = lastrow + 1

If Range("E2") = "" Then
MsgBox "You didn't enter the name of the customer!"
Range("E2").Select
Exit Sub
End If

If Range("E3") = "" Then
MsgBox "You didn't enter the surname of the customer!"
Range("E3").Select
Exit Sub
End If

Comment: Cells(nextBlankRow, 3) = Range("E2")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 4) = Range("E3")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 5) = Range("E4")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 6) = Range("E5")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 7) = Range("E6")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 8) = Range("E7")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 9) = Range("E8")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 10) = Range("E9")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 11) = Range("E10")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 12) = Range("E11")
Cells(nextBlankRow, 13) = Range("E12")
'MsgBox nextBlankRow
Dim p As Long, q As Long
p = 17
q = p + 1
Do While Cells(p, 3) <> ""
    Do While Cells(q, 3) <> ""

Comment: If Cells(p, 3) = Cells(q, 3) And Cells(p, 4) = Cells(q, 4) Then
           MsgBox "Duplicate Data! Will be removed from database!"
           Range(Cells(q, 3), Cells(q, 9)).ClearContents
        Else
        q = q + 1
        End If
    Loop
    p = p + 1
    q = q + 1
Loop
 
   
End Sub

Comment: @maygorodwen: Please, do not post code in comments. I cannot understand it. Please, edit your question and post here all your code, explaining on which line the error appear. Anyhow, the best way to obtain the last row (in column A:A, for instance) would be the next: `LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row`

Comment: Oh sorry about that....I will do so from now on. What lines of code does LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row replace? I think it may be much easier to use

Comment: @maygorodwen: All your posted code, except the declarations line...

Comment: I'm sorry to sound so inexperienced but I am not a coder, just trying to help my dad with his excel data base. Which line is the declarations line? Is it the Dim i As Long....

Comment: @maygorodwen: Yes. You declare variables starting with `Dim`...

Comment: so LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row replaces from lastrow = Cells.Find....?

Comment: Is there any data on the active sheet when it fails? If it's empty it will try and return row 0.

Comment: @maygorodwen: Yes. Why don't you try it? If it does not work as expected, you can switch it back...

Comment: I tried LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row ... it removes the run-time error 1004 but now when I type the name, surname and telephone number into the active sheet and press the add client button...it throws out the name and telephone number from their cells into a different cell and a message pops up that I did not enter the customer name

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook. yes I filled in the name, surname and contact number but when I click on add customer it takes me to the Visual Basics window where my macro module is and displays the error message

Comment: I kept playing around with the LastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).row and got the code to work...yay thank you so much for your patience and helping me. I will edit my question above to contain the solution